# What are the common website vulnerabilities, and the programming languages related to them?

Tags: programming-languages

As far as know, I must be careful with PHP, and I think Javascript. What else?

Comment: haha I thought you were going to be the one hacking, not in fear of being hacked.

Comment: Are you asking for common website vulnerabilities? You can find them in all languages if they are used incorrectly.

Comment: Please define your use of "hack" in this question. One might be inclined to flag as offensive here...

Comment: I believe the OP is asking which languages have gaping security flaws, so that he will be careful in using them, not because he wants to exploit them himself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Security vulnerabilities are (mostly) independent of the language involved (except for memory issues).

Instead, you should focus on tasks with potential vulnerabilities, such as processing user input or handling sensitive data.

Some things to watch out for:

- **Always use parameters in SQL**
- Always escape correctly (when generating HTML, JSON, Javascript strings, or anything else)
- Be **extremely** careful when executing code dynamically (eg, `eval`, automatic updates, etc)
- Always validate user input on the server

You should also read articles about security, such as the [Top 25 Most Dangerous Programming Errors](http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/).

Comment: +1 for "always use parameters in SQL". I actually find it's *easier* to code SQL that is properly parameterised, anyway! (though I guess that depends on which library you use)

Answer (score 1):

OWASP provides an annual report describing the top ten web application security flaws (see link below for description of the project and the most recent report).  As SLaks wrote, many vulnerabilities are independent of the language.  Web applications need to be designed with security in mind.

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project